# I can't understand! an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\int_{S}^{\infty}y\left(S,t\right)e^{-Rt}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial y\left(S,S+\tau\right)}{\partial S}e^{-R\tau}d\tau
$$

I don't understand how this is true. If incorrect, please explain the process.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing $t$ by $\tau=t-S,\; $ we have
$$\int\limits_{S}^{\infty}y\left(S,\;t\right)e^{-Rt}dt=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{ y\left(S,\;S+\tau\right)}e^{-R(\tau+S)}d\tau=e^{-RS}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{ y\left(S,\;S+\tau\right)}e^{-R\tau}d\tau.$$
Then 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\int\limits_{S}^{\infty}y\left(S,\;t\right)e^{-Rt}dt=\\
=-Re^{-RS}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{ y\left(S,\;S+\tau\right)}e^{-R\tau}d\tau+e^{-RS}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\partial y\left(S,\;S+\tau\right)}{\partial S}e^{-R\tau}d\tau}.$$